# What angle does the board need to be cut at?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, trigonometric-series

[image]If someone has a 2'' wide board and a 1 1/2'' wide board, and they want to cut the narrower board at an angle so the cut is 2'' long and the boards will fit together, what angle do they need to cut the board?

Here is what I've come up with so far.
cos (angle) = adj / hypotenuse 
cos (angle)= 1.5 / 2 
cos-1 (0.75)
= 41.40962211 degrees

I am not familiar with the functions sin, cos, or tan just yet, so my apologies if my work is confusing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am confused by your question. What do you mean by "the boards fit together"? If you could revise your question, we will be more likely to solve it (or at least assist you in solving it).

Comment: I added a picture, hope that clears up your confusion.

Comment: Looks like you were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The animation makes it obvious that $$\sin \theta = \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \frac{1.5}{2} = \frac{3}{4},$$ consequently $$\theta = \sin^{-1} \frac{3}{4} \approx 0.848062 \, \text{radians} \approx 48.5904^\circ.$$

Comment: Which is 90-WW1's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The piece you remove will be a right angled triangle with

a hypotenuse of $2$ and

one side of length $\frac 32$

you must cut at angle of

$$ \theta = \cos^{-1}( \frac 34 ) \approx 41.41^o $$